# Executing a Unix Shell Script in AWS or GCP Environment

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, unix, google-cloud-platform, scripting

I have developed a shell script which connects to the AWS EKS Cluster, Execute a kubectl command, get the result as JSON string and insert into AWS RDS MySQL DB. Tested the script in AWS Cloud Shell which is fine there. Now, I want to schedule the script (using CRON Scheduler may be ) every 30 minutes. I am exploring options on where to schedule the Unix Shell Job. Below are the options I can see from web :-

1. From an AWS EC2 Instance
2. Using AWS Systems Manager

For #1, I can start an EC2 instance free tier and schedule the cron job.
For #2, not very sure on how AWS Systems Manager works.

Is there any other approach to schedule a shell job in AWS or GCP ?

Comment: You can schedule it via lambda in aws.

Comment: Thanks @Riz. Do you have any reference on how to schedule it on Lambda ? Appreciate your help!

Comment: You can check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html and https://iam-j.github.io/jobs/cronjobs-on-ecs/ to do it in eventbrige or directly with ecs